# How to set tooltip to Ext.form.TextField where input type is file?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am new to extjs, and I want to set tooltip to field lable of Ext.form.TextField with input type file.
I try to do this by follwing code but its not working.

```
    Ext.override(Ext.form.Field, {
        afterRender : Ext.form.Field.prototype.afterRender.createSequence(function(){
            var qt = this.qtip;
            if (qt) {
                Ext.QuickTip.register ({
            target:  this,
            title: '',
            text: qt,
            enabled: true,
            showDelay: 20
                })
            }
        })
    });


   this.myTestComponent = new Ext.form.TextField({
       fieldLabel: 'My Field lable',
       qtip: 'My Field Tooltip',
       name: 'field1',
       scope: this,
       inputType: 'file',
       width: 150
    })
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? And are you using ExtJS 3? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I am using ExtJs 3, qtip: 'My Field Tooltip' is not working.
I want to set tooltip to field lable.
but my TextField's type is file, its not working

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I'll answer exactly to your question - if you want to add a tooltip, you can use this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var textFieldStreet = new Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel: 'My Field lable',
        //renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        name: 'field1',
        inputType: 'file',
        listeners: {
            render : function(c) {
                new Ext.ToolTip({
                    target : c.label.dom,
                    html: 'Label tooltip'
                });
                new Ext.ToolTip({
                    target : c.getEl(),
                    html: 'Field tooltip'
                });
            }
        } 
    });

    var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [textFieldStreet]
    });

})
```

**Notes:**

Tested with ExtJS 3.4.

Config `fieldLabel` is only used when `textfield` is rendered by a container which has been configured to use the FormLayout layout manager.

One disadvantage is the default "No file chosen" tooltip in Chrome and Mozilla.

You can see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o0q).

Comment: Thank you sir, I used your code. But still its not working

Comment: @AmitaPatil I've updated the answer with working fiddle.

Comment: it adds fieldLabel: 'fieldLabel'  3 times, and hides brows button and fileName field

Comment: Hello sir, it works but it shows both tooltips on brows button

Comment: @AmitaPatil Yes, this hint is part of the webkit browsers (see link in answer for more information and workarounds). In IE it is not a problem. But on field label, I think, tooltip works well on all browsers.

Comment: we have linux, i dont have any problem with 2 tooltips, but it shows both on one button (brows button) at the same time, 'No File Selected' hides my tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            name: 'field1',
            fieldLabel:'Label Descr',
            inputType: 'file',
            width: 250,
            listeners: {
                render : function(c) {
                    new Ext.ToolTip({
                        target : c.label.dom,
                        html: 'My tooltip'
                    });
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: It gives error - TypeError: c.label is undefined
 

target : c.label.dom,

Comment: if i not mistaken,the 'textfield' must be inside a panel with 'form' layout to create the label.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle, see if it helps: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o20

Comment: Thank you sir, but it still gives same error, TypeError: c.label is undefined
 

target : c.label.dom,

Comment: Strange, check if the listener is declare in the right place, under the textfield component, you could put a console.log(c) to see the textfield properties.